# remove other role column from wordpress user management page

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

I am using User Role Editor plugin to manage different user roles on my website, now on users list in admin section there are 2 columns Role and Other Role. The Role column is ok i want to remove that Other Role column, and also With user Role I want to append a link to send admin to change user role page.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally jquery help me to solve this issue, using jquery .ready i have hide the column that i need to hide and also append a link with user role.
thanks jquery